# SQL example data from database to schema query

Tags: sql, dynamic-sql, information-schema

I have a RDB with 10+ tables and 500 or so columns across the tables.  The data is received from different partners that send in the same type of information.  I am setting up a new partner and would like to send them a copy of the schema for their extract development to simplify the process and avoid receiving data mismatches. Pulling the schema is no problem but populating another "column" with example data becomes my issue...

I would like to populate a column with the top 1 record for that column and table so they can review the example format I prefer to receive.

Example:

```
SELECT
    table_catalog,
    table_name,
    column_name,
    data_type,
    character_maximum_length,
    datetime_precision,
    is_nullable,
    CAST('' AS VARCHAR(150)) AS "EXAMPLE_DATA",
    CAST('' AS VARCHAR(150)) AS "COL_DEFINITION"
INTO #TABLE_DEFS
FROM MY_TABLE.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS

UPDATE #TABLE_DEFS
   SET COL_DEFINTIION = (SELECT TOP 1 column_name FROM table_name X)
   WHERE X.table_name = #table_defs.table_name
   AND X.column_name = #table_defs.column_name
```

Is this possible?  Hopefully my example makes sense.

Thanks!

Comment: I would send your schema DDL.  Export it.  That is what it is for your problem.   ALSO I would run a class generator against your schema and generate .NET or Java objects.    Then you would just have to make notes about values like ZipCode or State 2 Letter code and positive or negative numbers.  Things like gender codes for example.

Comment: I am going to be sending them a copy of the schema but want the example data included per row..I could write a very long update routine but was hoping there is a faster or more dynamic way of approaching this using SQL.